# WHERE NOT SQL INSTRUCTION

Tags: mysql, sql

I have example like this: select this colors of pieces which are not a wheel and mass >=10 
and I have four ideas

1. `select color from A where not(name='wheel') and mass>=10`
2. `select color from A where mass>=10 and not(name='wheel')`
3. `select color from A where not name='wheel' and mass>=10`
4. `select color from A where (not name='wheel') and mass>=10`

Which one is correct? I think the first one is for sure ok, but how about the rest?

Comment: Simply try the four different version. Don't forget to have some NULL values in your table. (They tend to confuse beginners.)

Comment: select color from A where name<>'wheel' and mass>=10;

Comment: i know about <> and !=, but i must use NOT

Comment: You know, you could just Try it out?  That's the basis of testing...

Answer (score 1):

I usually use not for keyword (exists, in,like) only and keep <> or != for inverted tests. Not sure it's a convention, but i almost every time see this kind of query :

```
select color from A where name != 'wheel' and mass >= 10
```

Here's a good reference for syntax : http://www.sqlstyle.guide/, nothing about good usage of NOT keyword.

But you can consider your 4 queries as "correct".

Parenthesis have a mathemathical behaviour here, same result with or without in each of your example since there is only one element in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for clarity

```
select color from A where name <> 'wheel' and mass >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have only one table ,its better to use `<>` or `!=`

Answer (score 0):

Just to put my 2 pences on this as well :

In any RDBMS the `NOT` and `<>` operators result usually in the most consuming tasks of a query. When possible, it's always good to avoid them. Sometimes it is not possible, but sometimes it is.

Taking your query as an example: if `name` on table `A` has a very low cardinality, ie you can only have a few different `names` which are fixed by design, it's better to list them all but 'wheels', and thus avoid  `NOT` and `<>`

```
select color 
from A 
where name IN ('something','somethingelse','anotherthing') 
  and mass >= 10
```